# Problems linking external page to one page site

Tags: php, jquery, html, smooth-scrolling

Having issues linking external pages back to home page, which is a single page scroll.

My header.php file:

```
            <div class="navigation">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                <li><a class="various apply-button" data-membership="corporate" href="#contactForm">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And I'm using Smooth Scroll jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('a.logo, ul.nav a, #mmenu a, a.mobileLogo').bind('click',function(event){
                var $anchor = $(this);

                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top-50                
                }, 800);

                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

It works fine on the home page, but once I click a link to an external page, I can't get back. URL just reads test2.php#home-page instead of back to the index. If I simply add the entire URL to the href tag, the scroll quits working on the home page. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you add the whole URL, you can just split the string to extract the anchor.

```
href_arr = $anchor.attr('href').split("#");

$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $('#'+href_arr[1]).offset().top-50                
}, 800);
```